# My network printer isn't being discovered by other PCs

Tags: network-printer

My Canon LBP 800 is successfully installed on the print server, and prints as a local printer, but 'add printer' on the other PCs will go through the motions yet the printer does not appear on the 'printers and faxes' window.

- I have a USB printer installed on the same PC which works fine.
- The Canon LBP 800 uses a parallel connection
- I use *Windows XP Professional* across the network

Comment: Is the printer marked as shared on the network (on the print server)? By default, you don't share printers IIRC.

Comment: yes it is shared, what is IIRC?

Comment: "If I remember correctly". :) Do you see other shared ressources like folders? Or nothing at all? Later case, you might have different workgroups set?

Comment: lol i thought it was some obscure geeky term! my usb printer is shared in exact the same way, and works fine - the workgroup is correct

Comment: Weird, did you try installing the drivers manually? Maybe some driver issue - otherwise no idea right now.